# peerjs definitely typed definitions contains errors

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped, peerjs

When using the definitions provided by definitely typed at :

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/cc3d223a946f661eff871787edeb0fcb8f0db156/peerjs/peerjs.d.ts

I get the following error

```
"Cannot find name RTCDataChannel"
```

Are there any other dependencies I need to install?

Comment: You also need to install definitions for webrtc

Comment: still doesn't work, how can I get dependencies installed automatically?